# How to load a specific value from a database to dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a query which returns a data. Actually it has to **return only one row of data, but i have to take several records from different tables and they contain several values for one primary attribute**. There according to the query I get several rows. Now **I want to load one of the records(one cell  of a column) to a dropdownlist.** How can I do it?
This is my query

```
select emp.[App_no] 
    ,emp.[EMP_CALLING_NAME]
    ,emp.[EMP_INI]
    ,emp.[EMP_SURNAME]
    ,emp.[EMP_TITLE]
    ,emp.[EMP_NAMES_INI]
    ,emp.[EMP_FULLNAME]
    ,emp.[EMP_NIC]
    ,emp.[EMP_dob]
    ,emp.[EMP_GENDER]
    ,emp.[NAT_CODE]
    ,emp.[EMP_MARITAL_STATUS] 
    ,emp.[EMP_DATE_JOINED]
    ,emp.[EMP_CONFIRM]
    ,emp.[CX_CODE]
    ,emp.[DSMG_CODE]
    ,emp.[CAQT_CODE]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_ADDRESS1]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_ADDRESS2]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_ADDRESS3]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_CITY]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_TELEPHONE]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_MOBILE]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_PROVINCE]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_DISTRICT]
    ,emp.[EMP_TEM_ADDRESS1]
    ,emp.[EMP_TEM_ADDRESS2]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_ELECTORATE]
    ,emp.[EMP_TEM_ADDRESS3]
    ,emp.[EMP_TEM_CITY]
    ,emp.[EMP_PER_GD]
    ,bank.[BBRANCH_CODE]
    ,bank.[EBANK_ACC_NO]
    ,bank.[EBANK_ACC_TYPE_FLG]
    ,bank.[EBANK_ACTIVE_FLAG]
    ,bank.[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE]
    ,qual.[Qulif_code]
    ,lang.[lang_code]
    ,lang.[ability_type]
    ,ex.[From_date]
    ,ex.[To_date]
    ,ex.[Organization]
    ,ex.[designation]
    ,ex.[Cobtact_No]
    ,nation.[NAT_NAME]
    from [EMPLOYEE] emp, [EMP_BANK] bank,
    [QUALIF] qual, [LANG] lang,
    [Experience] ex, [NATIONALITY] nation
    where emp.App_no = bank.App_no and emp.App_no = qual.App_No 
    and emp.App_no = lang.App_no and nation.NAT_CODE = emp.[NAT_CODE]
    and emp.App_no = ex.App_no and emp.App_no=@num
```

This is how I bind data

```
ddlDesignations.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddlDesignations.DataTextField = "designation";
ddlDesignations.DataValueField = "designation";
ddlDesignations.DataBind();
```

This is how the dropdownlist appears
[image: image of the dropdownlist]

Comment: which column you wanted to show in dropdown ?

Comment: @Ahmar [designation] column

Comment: I want to avoid repeating the same record in the dropdownlist

Comment: If you need only `designation` to be displayed in the UI, then why are you fetching this much of unrelated values?   Not related to the answer, a general suggestion - Stop testing with junk values you may get confused.

Comment: Only [designation] column shown on the dropdown list, then change the query only return [designation] column from database end.

Comment: @Shahzad I have a interface to load. This ddl is just one thing in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick

```
DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "designation");
ddlDesignations.DataSource = distinctValues;
ddlDesignations.DataTextField = "designation";
ddlDesignations.DataValueField = "designation";
ddlDesignations.DataBind();
```

Here, first parameter in ToTable() is a boolean which indicates whether you want distinct rows or not. and the second parameter in the ToTable() is the column name based on which we have to select distinct rows. Only these columns will be in the returned datatable.

Comment: This worked. THanks for the answer. I  will accept it

Comment: Thanks @Mike Happy to help. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @ Mohit I tried to use the same code to few other dropdownlists in the in the interface but only the first one is working. Do you have nay idea why is that?

Comment: @ Mohit I have done a little mistake and I could find out the reason .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ` for this

```
var distinctdesignations = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(row => new {
                             designation = row.Field<string>("designation")
                           })
                           .Distinct();


ddlFamilyMembers.DataTextField = "designation"; 
ddlFamilyMembers.DataValueField = "designation;  
ddlFamilyMembers.DataSource = distinctdesignations;
ddlFamilyMembers.DataBind();
```